How to use the Preact and HTM with TypeScript?
It seems like it's possible, but I can't figure out how to do it.
Code below works in JS, but not in TS.
npm install htm
import { html } from 'htm/preact' // <= TS error here, can't find import

html`<div>hello</div>`


Are you sure you installed it? There are types provided by the module. Can you provide a reproduction in say StackBlitz or CodeSandbox?
